# Is there a way to see if someone is (already) online at Google Meet (free version)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-meet

The commercial versions of Google Meet seem to have an option to see if someone is online or not. Is there a way to see if someone is online in free versions of Google Meet?

If I join the "meeting room" of someone else, I'd like to see if the other person is already there (for me this means "is still in a previous meeting") or not.

[Track attendance in Google Meet (business)](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/10090454?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: There is no built-in way to get the attendance list but there might be third party tools.

Note: The  online prescence is available in all editions, the attendance report not.

---

The Help Center for Google Meet is the same for all editions. When there is a feature that has limitations for certain editions or that is not available all the editions, the help article mentions that. This is the case of the article that you are referring.

The online prescence of someone in a videocall is shown in all editions. The videocall link open open the "Ready to join?" page that allows the user to verify the camera and microphone settings. When these links are liked to a Calendar invite this page shows if someone else already was joined, otherwise show no one joined yet. By the other hand once one entetered the videocall it's possible to see participants. If they abandon the videcall they will be removed form the participant list.

**Regarding getting an attendance list**

Contrary as happens with some apps like Docs and Sheets, Meet doesn't have an easy way to extend it's features by end-users but you might find thir party tools in the [Google Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/). Also it might be possible that low code / no code platforms offer integrations with other tools that help you to get the attendance list.

Depending on the size of the group participationg in the videocall you might use simple things like asking type their name in the chat, fill a form among many possibilities.

**Related help articles**

- [Join a meeting](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/9303069?hl=en)
- [How to view people in Google Meet](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/9292748?hl=en)